# ViewPager not firing TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener after updated gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, android-tablayout

I'm using Viewpager with TabLayout and swipe between fragments setOnTabSelectedListener fired same as clicking tabs.

After updated gradle dependencies had problem that swipe don't fire setOnTabSelectedListener anymore, only when clicking tabs.

**Is there something needed to do differently when changed all dependencies from 22 to 23?**

Here is Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Here is how I do tabs to TabLayout:

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;

private void setupTablayout(){

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab1)));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab2)));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab3)));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Voids.savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), Voids.CHAT_SELECTED_TAB, tab.getPosition());
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    // Do first tab actions
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Do second tab actions
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug. If I had to guess, a combination of swiping and tapping is causing the state of the view pager to get wonky.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183776